# Сортировка массива по названию

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, сортировка

Есть массив. Его надо отсортировать так, чтоб порядок был следующий:
`Здравствуйте, Здравствуйте, Привет, Привет, Пока` . Каким образом этого можно добиться? Можно перебрать массив через `each или for var` и по условию добавить значение в начало или конец массива, а мне необходима очерёдность:

> 1. Здравствуйте
> 2. Привет
> 3. Пока

```js
var test = ["Привет", "Здравствуйте", "Привет", "Здравствуйте", "Пока"];

console.log(test)
```

Comment: Непонятно, по какому критерию определяется "очередность". Если по алфавиту, то, по идее, сначала должно быть "пока", а потом уже "привет".

Comment: @smellyshovel очерёдность по шаблону, не по буквам. сравнение чтоб было,первыми перебираем Здравствуйте и добавляем в начало,вторыми перебираем Привет и ставим после Здравствуйте если такое значение есть в массиве, затем перебираем Пока и ставим после привет. Я так себе это представляю.

Comment: А, вот оно что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var test = ["Привет", "Здравствуйте", "Привет", "Здравствуйте", "Пока"];


function retest(arr) {
  var art = arr.toString();
  var narr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < art.match(/Здравствуйте/g).length; i++)
    narr.push("Здравствуйте");
  for (var i = 0; i < art.match(/Привет/g).length; i++)
    narr.push("Привет");
  for (var i = 0; i < art.match(/Пока/g).length; i++)
    narr.push("Пока");
  return narr;
}
test = retest(test);

console.log(test);
```